# Does modification order contribute to happens-before relationship?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, happens-before

```cpp
// Thread 1
// do A
x.store(1, std::memory_order_release); // operation1

// Thread 2
// do B
x.store(2, std::memory_order_release); // operation2

// Thread 3
x.load(std::memory_order_acquire); // operation3
```

I've understood that if thread3 reads the value written by thread1, the release and acquire operations are *synchronized-with*, and effect of `A` is visible to thread3.
But what if the case is that:

- the modification order for `x` is 1, 2
- thread3 reads the value written by thread2, thus 2 *happens-before* 3.

Is there *happens-before* relationship between 1 and 3 ?
or intrinsically, does modification order contribute to *happens-before* relationship ?

Comment: The causality goes the other way round: "**[intro.races]/14** If an operation `A` that modifies an atomic object `M` happens before an operation `B` that modifies `M`, then `A` shall be earlier than `B` in the modification order of `M`."

Comment: That's right, but I just wonder the visibility of `A` to 3. Because you can never load an earlier value in the modification order, does this mean `A` is visible to 3?

Comment: If thread 3 reads B, then how do you know that A precedes B in modification order in the first place? Why do you assume that? Why does it even matter whether A happens-before a read in thread 3 - how can a conforming program tell the difference? Modification order is not by itself observable behavior - it's just a tool for reasoning about what observable behavior is or is not possible when the non-deterministic abstract machine executes a particular program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. there is no happens-before relationship between Operation 1 and Operation 3.

From [[atomics.order]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/atomics.order):

> An atomic operation A that performs a release operation on an atomic
>   object M synchronizes with an atomic operation B that performs an
>   acquire operation on M and takes its value from any side effect in the
>   release sequence headed by A.

... and unfortunately, Operation 2 is not in the release sequence headed by Operation 1 according to [[intro.races]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.races#5):

> A release sequence headed by a release operation A on an atomic object M is a maximal contiguous sub-sequence of side effects in the modification order of M, where the first operation is A, **and every subsequent operation is an atomic read-modify-write operation**.

As a result, we cannot build any [inter-thread happens-before relationship](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.races#9) between Operation 1 and other operations, so there is no [happens-before relationship](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.races#10) between Operation 1 and Operation 3.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you show thread 1 and thread 2 both operating on x in exactly the same way. Therefore, the relationship between thread 1 and thread 3 should be exactly the same as the relationship between thread 2 and thread 3.

Your example does *not* show any code lines that would constrain the order in which the three operations actually would happen.  In other words, just from looking at those three statements, there is no way to say whether the load operation would return `1`, or `2`, or some previous value of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, no there is no extra guarantees on overall ordering as a result of what memory ordering you use. There is no blocking at-all to allow this to happen.